# Selenium python server authentication

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, server

I am trying to pass server credentials when I open URL. I used for this the following code, but it does not work:

````
 keyboard.press_and_release("tab")
 keyboard.write("<pass>")
 keyboard.press_and_release("tab")
 keyboard.press_and_release("enter")
 driver.maximize_window()```

I also tried this code snipped but it still does not work.
driver.get("https://username:password@somewebsite.com/") 

Any other idea?

Thank you!
````

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and enter you password instead of

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
keyboard.press_and_release(Keys.TAB)
keyboard.send_keys("<pass>")
keyboard.press_and_release(Keys.TAB)
keyboard.press_and_release(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  

keyboard.send_keys('vpp')
E       AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tried with the following code that also returns some error:
```keyboard.write('vpp')
keyboard.press_and_release(Keys.TAB)```
conftest.py:36: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py:379: in send parsed = parse_hotkey(hotkey)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keyboard/__init__.py:344: in parse_hotkey
scan_codes = key_to_scan_codes(hotkey)
key = '\ue004',

Comment: Keyboard is the object of?

Comment: I did not instantiate keyboard object ... The code is as follows:
driver.get(<url>)
    
    keyboard.write(username)
    keyboard.send('tab')

After url is opened, a pop-up is displayed for entering the server authentication credentials.
   I suppose I should pass somehow the keyboard object to this pop-up ...

Comment: When that popup is displayed you need to that element by using temp = driver.find_element_by_id(id) then temp.send_keys() will work